# Statistics Question, Bayes Rule, Barometer Question

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages, bayes-theorem

Bayes rule states that P(A|B) = [P(B|A)P(A)]/P(B).

Let's suppose rain falls *one day in three*, and when it does a barometer shows rain with a probability of *0.7*, otherwise it has a *0.1* probability of showing rain. ***Find the probability, that on a random day, the barometer shows "rain".***

Does anyone know how to find the required probability by using Bayes Rule? Thank you in advance.

*EDIT* found very useful link as to what solution to use and when [When to use Total Probability Rule and Bayes' Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948888/when-to-use-total-probability-rule-and-bayes-theorem)

Answer (score 2):

Bayes' Rule is unnecessary for this question. What you need is the Law of Total Probability:

$$
P(A) = \sum_{i} P(A|B_i)P(B_i).
$$

In this case, where we have two possibilities: $B = \text{rain}$ and $\neg B = \text{no rain}$,you can write:

$$
P(A) = P(A|B) P(B) + P(A|\neg B)P(\neg B).
$$

therefore:

$$
P(\text{barometer shows rain}) = P(\text{barometer shows rain}| \text{rain}) P(\text{rain}) + P(\text{barometer shows rain}|\text{no rain})P(\text{no rain}).
$$

> Plugging in the values one gets $P(\text{barometer shows rain}) = 0.7 \times \left(\frac{1} {3}\right) + 0.1 \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{3}\right) = 0.3.$